# Plank vinyl flooring , the glue will not dry

Tags: vinyl-flooring, vinyl

I decided to replace the entire house with a glue down plank vinyl flooring. I followed the instructions and used the recommended glue to put it in place.

Two days after putting the floor down, when moving the appliances in I could see wet glue coming through the cracks. I cleaned it up and assumed I placed too much glue in that area. That was just the beginning of cleaning up glue. Months have gone by and here and there in the kitchen I would see wet glue come through the seams. Everyday that went by I was hoping it would finally dry.

Well, it’s been over a year and decided to peal a tile up only to see the concrete slab and the glue I put down was as wet as the day I put it down. I don’t know why the glue never dried in the kitchen and the rest of the house is fine.
I don’t have any water pipes that run through the slab, so it’s not a water leak.
The house was built in the mid-60s. The common floor type that was the glue down sheet vinyl with cut back black glue. I still had a hit and miss of this old glue still on the concrete but, it was mostly in another room where the new floor is fine.
I don’t know where to start to fix this problem. 
I can pull up these tiles and clean the glue off the slab and reuse the tiles, but what glue will adhere to the concrete and the tile. 
 I’m looking for a solution to this mysterious problem.
Hope you can help me,
[image]

Comment: What is the glue that you used (model number / link if possible)? What is the method you used for gluing it down?

Comment: The glue that was used was Roberts 2057 and was put on by a roller. The kitchen is the only place that the glue is not drying.

Comment: The vinyl floor manufacture recommended Roberts 2057? I read that it's for VCT tile, which is not that same as the flooring you have.  Maybe they did recommend it, and it's just marketed for VCT tile, you sure they didn't recommend a slightly different one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to bet that you used a "mastic" based tile setting adhesive, which would have been the wrong type for a kitchen. Mastic is an organic compound (from a Mastic tree) and will re-liquefy with moisture. not only is it bad for kitchens and bathrooms, but if the concrete was not sealed, moisture can come up from below and continually re-liquefy your mastic, even if it has dried. If it was mastic based, you may need to pull everything up, clean it off and reapply with a waterproof acrylic based tile compound.

Comment: Roberts 2057 was the glue

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake was using a roller so I’m sure you put way to much on . Secondly that product works like a contact cement . You need to trowel it on and when it’s no longer yellow , meaning it’s all clear, that’s when you can begin to apply your floor . I’m positive you rolled it on and immediately placed the floor on it trapping all that moisture. It needs air to dry and does not even get tacky until it’s clear. That mold coming up is out of control man .